# Image upload issue with input type file on button click in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

This is the HTML part of my code.

```
<ul class="submenu">
  <li>
    <button id="button-openfile">
      <input type="file"/><span">Open File</span>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li><button id="button-save" onclick="getValue()">Save</button></li>
</ul>
```

And this is the JavaScript file code:

```
$('#button-openfile input').change(app.callbacks.openFile);
```

I want to execute a function app.callbacks.openFile on first li button.
I get a window to upload a file in Chrome browser, but nothing happens in Firefox and IE>10.
Where is the issue?

Comment: It is improper to put an `<input>` inside of a `<button>`.

Comment: why do you need <button> tag you can remove that and do your JS validations on <input type="file"> itself